# SQL taking a one-to-many delimited list in a table column and transforming it into a one-to-one relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database, with a specific column I am trying to extract data from. The data is concatenated together into a delimited list, with the delimited being a semicolon.

So lets say that

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB
from TableA
```

produces a result set like this

```
ROW 1
ColumnA - 1
ColumnB - value 1; value 2; value 3

ROW 2
ColumnA - 2
ColumnB - value 4; value 5; value 6
```

The delimiter is always a semicolon. I have a secondary table which I want to store the values in on a one-to-one basis, lets call it TableB

So I want a dataset like:

```
1 | value 1
1 | value 2
1 | value 3
2 | value 4
2 | value 5
2 | value 6
```

Can anyone help me with the SQL code to do this type of transformation?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server split".

Comment: Not sure why I didnt see the above solution when I was searching SO. My mistake, that's what I needed.